# How to set Vim's color scheme search directory?

Tags: vim

Using Vundle to manage packages and I installed a color scheme package. Would like to redirect vim to search in that folder instead of the default. Could copy the color schemes to the default folder but that makes it pointless to use vundle for this.

Comment: If you used Vundle to install the colorscheme plugin, and you did it right, then that's all you need to do. The whole point of Vundle is that you don't need to fiddle with your runtime path.

Comment: @glts Welp I feel silly now. All I needed was to call vundle before setting the scheme. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are right: it's pointless to use vundle to manage colorshemes.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Vundle to install the colorscheme plugin, and you did it right, then that's all you need to do. The whole point of Vundle is that you don't need to fiddle with your runtime path. –  glts